# Unable to save Bitmap Image

Tags: android, bitmap, bitmapimage

Hi I Am Trying to save my new bitmap image after applying filter into the SD-card or gallery. I am using this Code to save my bitmap that I have found on Stack overflow as well, but this code is not working for me

```
public void saveImage(View view) {

    /*MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),newBitmap,"Image-Name","description");*/
    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File myDir = new File(root + "/saved_images");
    myDir.mkdirs();
    Random generator = new Random();
    int n = 10000;
    n = generator.nextInt(n);
    String fname = "Image-"+ n +".jpg";
    File file = new File (myDir, fname);
    if (file.exists ()) file.delete ();
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        newBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Toast.makeText(this,"Image Saved In SD Card",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Please let me know If I am doing any thing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please explain, **in detail**, what "is not working for me" means.

Comment: And add the full logcat output with the explanation please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you have added permission to write to sdcard

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```